# How can I read attributes added to my activity from ActivityTrackingRecord

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, event-tracking

I've added `TypeDescriptionProvider` to my activity class (*`SequentialWorkflow`*). I tracking I have `ActivityTrackingRecord` record. Record has `ActivityType` and in it attributes but I cannot see attribute added by me. How can I read value from `TypeDescriptionProvider` in workflow tracking ?

Comment: Can you please provide sample code for context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add meta attribute to your property

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
```

Sample

```
public static DependencyProperty TestProperty 
  = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Test", typeof(string), typeof(YourActivity));


[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[ValidationOption(ValidationOption.Optional)]
[Browsable(true)]
[Description("Enter ....")]
public string Test
{
   get { return ((string)(base.GetValue(YourActivity.TestProperty))); }
   set { base.SetValue(YourActivity.TestProperty, value); }
}
```